# Regex removing when match the link behavior- Python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to remove the entire link:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAJv1l4BATlBOVqhEEaqrVNojJPWnID9Nk0
```

When the link contains `ACo` the regex should remove from my pattern the entire link.

`regex2 = re.compile(r"\bhttps?://www.linkedin.com/in/\b[^in]+")`

For some reason I am not getting this to work, the idea is to remove when the behaviour of the link starts with 'ACo' (Capital A and Capital C) after the */in/*

We have 4 links, I am only want to print, `https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao1` and `https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao2`.

```py
unique_hrefs = ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao1','https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao2','https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAI3JyABlHv1LxXa27GHFneEbdrqAtMu9eY','https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAABWYG0kB8IXhFzDTCFGOwAZ18YbXprOLcmg']
    
regex = re.compile(r"\bhttps?://www.linkedin.com/in/\b[^in]+")

regex2 = re.compile(r"""\bhttps?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/ACo[^<>"'\s]*""")

filtered = [i for i in unique_hrefs if regex.search(i) and regex2.search(i)]

for i in filtered:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `r"""\bhttps?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/ACo[^<>"'\s]*"""`?

Comment: still showing 
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAABWYG0kB8IXhFzDTCFGOwAZ18YbXprOLcmg
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAI3JyABlHv1LxXa27GHFneEbdrqAtMu9eY
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAACxLxqoB5AY2HJD2x64sCPbD4Yll4I0JcbM
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAClna3cBO-vt7mItnD4T4HjhBWmnWgn-g6w
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAACxFDKEB4O5sU5VQ3NxM4N8A419rHJmfl8U

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, reproducible example.  See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just added it into the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
unique_hrefs = ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao1','https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao2','https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAAAI3JyABlHv1LxXa27GHFneEbdrqAtMu9eY','https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACoAABWYG0kB8IXhFzDTCFGOwAZ18YbXprOLcmg']
pattern = re.compile(r'https?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/ACo')
results = list(filter(lambda x: not pattern.match(x), unique_hrefs))
print(results)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##jdBBT8IwHAXw@z5Fb@sSsjk4iCTGdOgGBsPFxE0xptuKrXRt6f5zwy8/IRDDDe/v/ZL3zA64VqO@F5XRFpBlTqPEtmEf3LJ1jW7Rm8sBTD0JgrZtfSnUhpVC@YWuAqGCL0116A4uZoYXMmSqCSHz0eOORHL2HS66lA6vk1ms2ENe2i2Bp@aGZf9RopcsudpE43nK45/752mcLFvyGo6zPDV2uSiqT/fdMRSAWbXfZ9mhbYRk2B7xu6O@@uNXZ77rOZbVjYTDN1LUgNdC7iksaZWXFHUTpDSgk@9XFAqOO2@Azm/1PMdYoQCfKK/vfwE).

**Results**: `['https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao1', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/joao2']`.

Comment: In case I have another URL that I want to be excluded

`pattern = re.compile(r'https?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/ACo')

pattern1 = re.compile(r'https?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/search')

results = list(filter(lambda x: not pattern.match(x) and pattern1.match(x), unique_hrefs))

print(results)`

Comment: @user15140929 `pattern = re.compile(r'https?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/(?:ACo|search)')`. `(?:ACo|search)` means either `ACo` or `search`.

Comment: For some reason is not removing the URL where we have search after the /in/

`https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetNetwork=%5B%22F%22%5D&facetConnectionOf=%5B%22ACoAACuTLOgBfNC2cMU5XthAOz8eKEa7yL-7ioc%22%5D&origin=SHARED_CONNECTIONS_CANNED_SEARCH`

Comment: `regex= re.compile(r'https?://www\.linkedin\.com/in/ACo')
 regex1= re.compile(r'https?://www\.linkedin\.com/search')
 results = list(filter(lambda x: not regex.match(x) and regex1.match(x), unique_hrefs))
   
 print(results)
`

Comment: @user15140929 The `search` is not after `in`. Use [this code](https://tio.run/##jZJdT8IwFIbv@RW7QbZEmYwQkISQrowPxS0RjKAYUsYZq2xt7ToHxv@OExbjlXrRpMl58/Q851TsVchZ/XCgseBSaRJKKaOvKSxDCUGidbSnSqiUSNqmmWVZNaJsC2vKqj6PTcrMF054rXL@Z8b6I4MwRwiN6td7ZEfDt9p4NyNWczDsM3BWa/mK1G16BfP/UOyH@eBya7dGs7D/3pvi/sDL0GOtNV/NhPTGfrz5jZIAkX5oSkjSSCWmAC4iMLsB8UG5oDIut51ywy5bVj8/5Ubv7FjCnDHwFeXMC4r6sRmcTsfexg5cbPm3942ZCpH33oIbhzT344sm5X5B4ZJuKOtMhujO6S2x57oOno48d7LEKL/3lhMH3eFh5bkkiFIgWb4aCV8tCxqBLk9G3ZPS4ttpcZTSu@3TdD5OekbFKBWGOSaiidIDGuVUPSLxak20XVtjXGnFU9WYKD/Ud8a59vNzGEZJSMqUXqCMw@ET).

Comment: Thank you dude you are a star!